# How to upgrade pimcore from 6.8 to 6.9?

Tags: pimcore

I want to upgrade pimcore version from 6.8 to 6.9, but I don't find the update option at admin settings.

Comment: I have updated php as requirement into php8.0, but now this error/:                          
            Problem 1
    - cache/integration-tests 0.16.0 requires php ^5.4|^7 -> your PHP version (8.0.5) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - cache/integration-tests 0.16.0 requires php ^5.4|^7 -> your PHP version (8.0.5) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - cache/integration-tests 0.16.0 requires php ^5.4|^7 -> your PHP version (8.0.5) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - Installation request for cache/integration-tests ^0.16.0 -> satisfiable by cache/integration-tests[0.16.0].

Answer (score 2):

You don't need PHP 8 for Pimcore 6.9. PHP 8 is only required for Pimcore X.
To upgrade from Pimcore 6.8 to 6.9 adjust your composer.json and run **COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 composer update**.
Make sure you do have a complete backup before doing that.

Further information can be found in the official docs here: https://pimcore.com/docs/pimcore/6.9/Development_Documentation/Installation_and_Upgrade/Updating_Pimcore/index.html